# Rewrite recipient address in java mail session

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

The application is running on Jboss server and using JNDI for getting email session. 
What I am trying to do is sending email to different address than passed to email api.

Application is passing recipient email address like:

PREFIX_email@example.com

I would like to strip PREFIX_ before sending the message. Preferable solution needs to be as transparent as possible.

Is there any ready to use solution for such case? 
What is best way of handling that?

Comment: I cannot change application code. So as API calls parameters. I need add another layer bes t on JNDI level.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. The only thing I know is that if functionality needs to change, code changes are involved.

Comment: I cannot change application code but I can add module to server or change JNDI mapping. Sometimes you can change functionality by changing configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the Session properties to redirect the email to another server, you have three choices:

1. Configure the other server to dump all messages into a single INBOX,
   then write a JavaMail program to fetch the messages from the INBOX,
   modify the email addresses, and send the modified message to the
   real SMTP server.
2. Write a "fake" SMTP server the accepts the message, rewrites the email addresses,
   and sends the message to the real SMTP server.  You could use JavaMail to help with this.
3. Configure the SMTP server to do the address rewriting for you
   before forwarding the message.  sendmail can certain do this, I don't know about others.

Comment: You right it should be easy and possible to create software witch such functionality. That is why I really asked for ready to use solution.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing that does **exactly** what you want, out of the box.  But you can certainly configure sendmail to do it.  The other choices require you to write some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for **development** purpose I can recommend you a good solution for mocking `javax.mail.Session`.

A github project **[javaMail extension](https://github.com/m-szalik/javamail/wiki)** adds **file transport** that allows to:

- save mails to files in `text` format instead of sending them
- save mails to files in `mbox` format instead of sending them
- add log info instead of sending email

Comment: It would actually work if there was javamail-javamail-transport with ability to configure interim modifications.

Comment: To keep it most generic I think there should be ability to parse and rewrite whole body of message. For instance I can find it useful to add BCC recipients or remove attachments.

Comment: It's not implemented, but you're right, it can be useful. Please create issue on GitHub. You can also add this feature on your own.

Comment: Thanks, That is something I am thinking about but I am always too busy.